# What is tuition fee and type of residence permit for the spouse of EU citizen for a Dutch Master degree after the completion of the pre-Masters?

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands, eu-citizens, eu-spouses

I am non-EU citizen who is spouse to an EU citizen (non-Dutch working in the Netherlands as expat). A few days ago I got accepted to the pre-Master program after the successful completion of which I will be automatically enrolled to the Master studies.

I am 29 y.o. and will be 30 at the time of expected beginning of the Master studies and never done any studies in the EU/EEC, if it is important.

Currently, the type of my residence permit is Familielid EU/EER and it covers the period of all studies.

1. While I clearly understand what the tuition fee is for the pre-Master, I have doubts whether I will be qualifying for EU/EEC fee in the future, which is a big deal (approximately €15 000 for non-EU/EEC citizen yearly vs. about €2 300 for EU/EEC citizens).
2. I got a letter from the university asking me to apply for change of my residence permit type if it's not 'study'.

Hence, I have a few questions. Condidering my situation, should I change the type of my residence permit as asked by the university? If so, will it impact my chances to be eligible for the EU/EEC tuition fee in the future? In fact, I just generally wonder if I am eligible because the difference in the fee is just so big...

Comment: I don't know about the tuition, but requiring you to change to a student residence permit makes absolutely no sense whatsoever in the context of the EU free movement directive.  I looked at the relevant pages from two Dutch universities and neither addressed your situation.  If I were you I would call someone and ask.  If they don't seem to understand what your residence card is, explain that even though it is not a student residence permit it permits you to study in the Netherlands.